# Can a sorcerer convert spells inside his Ring of spell storing into sorcery points?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, sorcerer

Let’s say Bob is a second level sorcerer attuned to a Ring of spell storing. His buddy Fred casts some spells inside of his Ring. But greedy Bob wishes to convert the energy of these stored spells into sorcery points (as a bonus action, as per the Font of Magic feature). Is Bob allowed to do so ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

## No

> ***Converting a Spell Slot to Sorcery Points***. As a Bonus Action on your turn, **you can expend one spell slot** and gain a number of sorcery points equal to the slot's level.

Casting the spell from the ring of spell storing or simply converting that spell is not **expending one spell slot**, it's casting a spell (or using the ring).

More specifically, the Ring of Spell Storing stores **spells**, not **spell slots**, although it is limited by the spell slots.

> This ring stores spells cast into it, holding them until the attuned wearer uses them.

Comment: Also spell slots are tecnically Fred's anyways, Bob shouldn't be stealing others' slots for sorcery shenanigans.

Comment: @Tiggerous That's better for another question, feel free to ask. As a quick comment, I **do** think it leads to some balance problems, e.g. a full caster providing "spell slots" for the Sorcerer, but I don't think this has place in the scope of this specific question.